# Glassfish2.1 expects JSP while runing a JSF2.1 application

Tags: web-applications, jsf-2, glassfish-2.x

I am trying to run a jsf 2.1 application on Glassfish2.1. WAR file deploys successfully, but when I run the application, it gives HTTP 404 error. In the log, I can see the following

```
SEVERE: PWC6117: File "C:\Project\CA\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.sunappsrv91\v2domain2\applications\j2ee-modules\fal\search.jsp" not found
```

I wonder why it is expecting JSP, the URL it should be looking for is fal/search.jsf. I have run this application on JBoss7.1, and it runs perfectly there. There are no JSPs in my applications, I have created .xhtml files.
Here is the relevent content of my **web.xml**

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

<!-- Maintain page state on client side  --> 
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>client</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

And **faces-context.xml**

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/search.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/info.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
  </navigation-rule>
```

I tried adding *.jsp in the url-pattern of this servlet in web-xml, and that didn't work either. I got

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: PWC1232: Exceeded maximum depth for nested request dispatches: 20
```

So why is it looking for JSP?? Is there a way to solve this?

---

We were not able to solve this on Glassfish 2.1. Finally we moved to JBoss 7.1.

---

Comment: Isnt it `<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.face</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>`

Comment: I don't think that'd make any difference in this case, Because I am not facing any issue with *.face or *.faces URL-pattern.

Comment: It seems that glassfish2.x will not work with jsf2.x. We either have to upgrade glassfish to 3.x or downgrade jsf to 1.x.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that glassfish2.x will not work with jsf2.x. We either have to upgrade glassfish to 3.x or downgrade jsf to 1.x. I upgraded glassfish to make it work.